# Why does using list iterator loop forever?

Tags: java, list, loops, collections, iterator

In my code I have the following situation:

```
List cedolini = (List) Bean_Dati.getListaRisultati("ListaCertificazioni");

for (Iterator iterator = cedolini.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    System.out.println("TEST");
}
```

At this time the List named **cedolini** contains only an element that is an instance of a class named **Certificazioni**, I see it using the debugger.

The problem is that when the previous code is performed it enter in an infinite loop and I don't obtain a single **TEST** printed in the stacktrace but something like it:

```
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
....
....
....
```

and it still continue entering into an infinite loop.

Why? What am I missing? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Tip: print out a more useful "debug" message in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you never call `iterator.next()`, so `iterator.hasNext()` will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

You are not pulling the next element from the iterator. In your loop you should call

```
iterator.next()
```

If you look at your `for` loop,

```
for (Iterator iterator = cedolini.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
```

You will see that the boolean condition `iterator.hasNext()` will always be true if you're not taking the next element from the iterator, which will lead to your infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

call this in your loop

```
iterator.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you don't **update** the iterator to the next element in the iteration.

It's like you to do (imagine to have an array named *list*):

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; )
    System.out.println("TEST");
```

and you don't update *i*: `i++`.

You should change your loop adding `iterator.next()`:

```
for (Iterator iterator = cedolini.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); iterator.next())
    System.out.println("TEST");
```